CMake: Select the correct lib file depending on architecture and build config
I have a CMake-project where I want to include a 3rd party library with the following directory structure:
include/xx.h
x86-debug/xx.lib
x86-release/xx.lib
x64-debug/xx.lib
x64-release/xx.lib

I want to be able to build my project for all four of these configurations. How do I instruct CMake to link with the correct lib file depending on which architecture and build config (debug/release) I pass to cmake?
I have tried constructing the string "x86-debug" from variables accessible within the CMake script, but I have been unable to find variables that contain the build config and the architecture.

What have you tried? How did it not do what you wanted? Please [edit] and tell us.

@Friedrich I haven't tried anything other than reading the CMake documentation to try and find any kind of builtin variable containing the strings "x86"/"x64" and "debug"/"release" but haven't found any.
